# Unity Networking: can't spawn scene objects on all clients

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity-networking

I can't really figure out how to solve my problem. I have been looking for an answer but I couldn't find anything.

I have a button in my scene that can be pressed both by client and host. When the button is pressed, it creates a cube in the scene. The problem is that: the cube can be created only by the host and the host is the only user that can see it and manipulate it. 
My code is:

```
public class CreateCube : NetworkBehaviour {


        GameObject cubo;
        float lastCollisionTime=0;
        float collisionTime=0;

        void OnCollisionExit(Collision other) {

                collisionTime = Time.time;
                if (collisionTime - lastCollisionTime >1.5) {
                    CmdCreaCubo ();
                    lastCollisionTime = collisionTime;
                }
            }
            }
        }
        [Command]
        void CmdCreaCubo(){
            GameObject cubo=Instantiate(Resources.Load("MyPrefabs\\Oggetti\\CubeGrasp")) as GameObject;
            cubo.transform.position = new Vector3 (-5.88f, 7.51f, -19f);
            cubo.name = "CubeGrasp";
            NetworkServer.Spawn (cubo);

        }
}
```

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you so much

Comment: Does your NetworkManager have the CubeGrasp as registered spawnable prefab?

Comment: yes it has the CubeGrasp as registered spawnable prefab @LapisLazuli

Answer (score 0):

Instead using simple Instantiate you should need to use [**Network.Instantiate**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Instantiate.html)

> The given prefab will be instanted on all clients in the game.
>   Synchronization is automatically set up so there is no extra work
>   involved.